# Determine if installed extensions are free or paid

Tags: extensions, magento-1

My magento site contains lot of extensions. I want to know which are among them are free and which are to be purchased (not free). Is there any way to find this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome Kishore in SE. I don't think you will be able to find out that. You will have to manually check for each by may be googling extension name.

Comment: I have closed this  question as off topic.... You need to ask this question at http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @AmitBera how is this question meta?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get a complete list without manually searching for the extensions, but you can at least get a list of all free extensions that have been installed via Magento Connect, with this command:

```
php downloader/mage.php list-installed
```

(or by looking at the Magento Connect backend)

In some cases that will give you a good starting point and reduce the number of extensions you need to check manually.

Comment: I checked magento connect manager. But there is no list under "Manage Existing Extensions" section. It seems no extensions are installed via Magento Connect. All are installed manually I guess. Now what should I do to find all the paid extension.

Comment: Google their names.

Comment: while googling I find some extensions come under both paid and free versions. Now how could I know the functionality of which it is installed. Being a new in magento I am confused. I am asked to list all the paid extensions of my site.

Comment: There is no standard way, it depends on the extension. Check for readme files or release notes, compare the version number in `etc/config.xml`, and if everything fails, download the free version and compare.